# X problems on Fedora 15

Tags: fedora, xorg, upgrade

I just upgraded from F13 to F15 using the Installation DVD and it looked all went fine. When I first booted into F15, gdm was having troubles starting up. I tried removing Xorg and reinstalled and issued `Xorg -configure`. It came up with `Screens found, but none have usable configuration. FATAL ERROR: No screens found`

**Attachments:**

[`Xorg.0.log`](http://pastie.org/1988127) - Error log

[`/root/xorg.conf.new`](http://pastie.org/1988131) - file created when doing `Xorg -configure`.

[`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`](http://pastie.org/1988133) - My old `xorg.conf` file I was using for my Intel card. Originally got from the Nvidia Proprietary installer.

I'm curious about these lines

```
[   117.519] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   117.519] Refusing to touch device with a bound kernel driver
[   117.519] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
```

I just want to know if this can be corrected, before I go do a fresh install. I never thought an upgrade would be such a pain in the bottom.

**EDIT:**

I just found these line in my `dmesg`

```
[    5.144255] systemd[1]: /usr appears to be on a different file system than /.
This is not supported anymore. Some things will probably break (sometimes even silently) in mysterious ways. Consult 
http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/separate-usr-is-broken for more information.
```

and the above link mentions there are 23 obvious cases during an F15 install.

Could this be a reason for my X Problems? If so, how do I merge my `/usr` back to `/`?

The [complete dump of `dmesg`](http://pastebin.com/ajgjku1z), just in case it happens to give you enough clues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, congratulations on very complete diagnostics information. Your old /etc/X11/xorg.conf shows that you were using the `vesa` driver. You don't want to do that. Also, the X log shows X could not find anything but the `vesa` driver. Check what driver supports your Intel card (I don't see the card information explicitly mentioned anywhere) and make sure that driver is installed. Or just install all drivers, and these days, X will likely autodetect the card. Feel free to add the card information if you want. If you don't know what it is, `lspci` will likely show it.

The warning

> /usr appears to be on a different file system than /.

is coming from `systemd`, which you have installed, judging by dmesg. See http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/commit/?id=80758717a6359cbe6048f43a17c2b53a3ca8c2fa.

No, this has nothing to do with your X problems. The warning

> Refusing to touch device with a bound kernel driver

is vesa-specific. See
http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-video-vesa/commit/?id=b1f7f190f9d4f2ab63d3e9ade3e7e04bb4b1f89f

Again, you don't want to use vesa, except as an emergency fallback.

Comment: Yeah, you were right about the driver. I had to install xorg-x11-drv-intel package to get this working, but now gdm starts and gets me to the login screen where neither my keyboard nor mouse works. I've dealt with this situation before, but I forgot the fix. Thanks! Btw, I always thought vesa is the default driver for Intel's cards.

Comment: @asgs: Maybe also a X issue. The mouse at least probably is.  You should probably post a new question for this if you are going to ask here, since you'll need to post all new diagnostic information. (I'd probably post the X logs and X config again at least). `vesa` is only used when nothing else is available. AFAIK, Intel has a relatively good attitude towards free drivers, and in fact works with the community to create them. So you should not have to use `vesa` here unless your card is super brand new or something.

Comment: No need. I got it done. I was missing the `X11`'s `keyboard` and `mouse` drivers missing. Thanks again!